# Why is this if statement returning true?

Tags: php

Why is this returning true? Party Bounce and Slide 13 x18 is not in the if statements?

```
print_r($btypes);
        //Array ( [0] => 11x13 Red and Yellow 2 [1] => Party Bounce and Slide 13 x 18 )

        if(in_array("12x15 Purple and Yellow 2" || "11x13 Red and Yellow 1" || "12x15 Yellow and Purple old" || "11x13 Red and Yellow 2" || "12x15 Purple and Yellow 1" ,$btypes) && 
        in_array("Bootcamp Obstacle Course" ||  "Terminator Torment Obstacle Course" || "Lizard Obstacle Course" || "Bugs Obstacle Course" || "Nemo Obstacle Course",$btypes))
        {
            return "Standard Bouncy Castle and an Obstacle Course";
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: invalid php syntax `bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )`

Comment: str1 || str2 does not seem like you want to me. You should rather do in_array(...) || in_array(...)

Comment: Please read the documentation of the tools you use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: create an array of accepted values and use array_intersect between $btypes and the accepted values. If the return on array_intersect has a value, return your message.

Comment: thank you. is there any easier way instead of creating lots of in_array() statements

Comment: sorry i am not an expert so if you could provide some sample code it would be great

Comment: note: `in_array(true, $array)` will always return `true` if `$array` contains a truthy value, and always return `false` if empty or have only falsey values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution which is easier to manage and even more important.. read.

```
$attributes = [
    "12x15 Purple and Yellow 2", 
    "11x13 Red and Yellow 1", 
    "12x15 Yellow and Purple old",
    "11x13 Red and Yellow 2", 
    "12x15 Purple and Yellow 1"
];

$types = [
    "Bootcamp Obstacle Course",
    "Terminator Torment Obstacle Course",
    "Lizard Obstacle Course",
    "Bugs Obstacle Course",
    "Nemo Obstacle Course"
];

if(array_intersect($btypes, $attributes) !== [] && array_intersect($btypes, $types) !== []){
    return "Standard Bouncy Castle and an Obstacle Course";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`"12x15 Purple and Yellow 2" || "11x13 Red and Yellow 1"` is a logical expression. In boolean context, any string except for `""` and `"0"` is [evaluated as `TRUE`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). The expression above has the same value as `TRUE || TRUE` and its value is `TRUE`.

By default, [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) uses `==` to compare its first argument against each element of the array passed as the second argument.

The first argument you pass to `in_array()` is `TRUE` and it is `==` to any string that is not `""` or `"0"`. All the strings in `$btypes` are `==` to `TRUE` and `in_array()` returns `TRUE`.

Read about how PHP [compares values of different types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types) and [how different values behave when they are compared using `==` and `===`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Depending what you want to achieve, I recommend you to use `array_intersect()` and/or `array_diff()` to get the values that are also present in `$btypes`.

```
$sizes = [
    '12x15 Purple and Yellow 2',
    '11x13 Red and Yellow 1',
    '12x15 Yellow and Purple old',
    '11x13 Red and Yellow 2',
    '12x15 Purple and Yellow 1',
];
$courses = [
    'Bootcamp Obstacle Course',
    'Terminator Torment Obstacle Course',
    'Lizard Obstacle Course',
    'Bugs Obstacle Course',
    'Nemo Obstacle Course',
];

$btypes = [
    '11x13 Red and Yellow 2',
    'Party Bounce and Slide 13 x 18',
];

if (count(array_intersect($sizes, $btypes)) &&
    count(array_intersect($courses, $btypes))) {
    // At least one size and at least one course are present in $btypes
    return "Standard Bouncy Castle and an Obstacle Course";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting your code makes it easier to follow what is going on here:

```
<?php
function is_bouncy_obstacle() {
    $btypes = [
        '11x13 Red and Yellow 2',
        'Party Bounce and Slide 13 x 18'
    ];
    if(
        in_array(
            "12x15 Purple and Yellow 2" || 
            "11x13 Red and Yellow 1" || 
            "12x15 Yellow and Purple old" || 
            "11x13 Red and Yellow 2" || 
            "12x15 Purple and Yellow 1"
            , 
            $btypes
        ) && 
        in_array(
            "Bootcamp Obstacle Course" ||  
            "Terminator Torment Obstacle Course" || 
            "Lizard Obstacle Course" || 
            "Bugs Obstacle Course" || 
            "Nemo Obstacle Course"
            ,
            $btypes
        )
    )
    {
        return "Standard Bouncy Castle and an Obstacle Course";
    }
}

var_dump(is_bouncy_obstacle());
```

Output:

```
string(45) "Standard Bouncy Castle and an Obstacle Course"
```

So it returns a string, not true.  But if you use the above string in a comparison it is considered true.

Importantly `in_array` takes two arguments: a needle and a haystack.  You are looking for a needle in a haystack. Argument order matters.

Example use of `in_array`:

```
var_dump(in_array('apple', ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']));
var_dump(in_array('apple', ['banana', 'papaya', 'sultana']));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Back to your code.

Consider:

```
var_dump('foo');
var_dump('foo' || 'bar');
var_dump(in_array('foo' || 'bar', ['baz']));
var_dump(in_array(true, ['qux']));
```

Output:

```
string(3) "foo"
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

The last feels like a bit of an oddity! This is due to loose comparison being the default for `in_array`.

You'll need to rewrite your conditionals.

Comment: If you down-vote please provide explanation, or help me improve this answer.  I appreciate the OP's method needed a rewrite, but that is not what was asked.